# Convert PHP to Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I convert this instruction :

```
<script>
<?php
 echo "sectionsPreview=".json_encode($this->groups).";\n";
 echo "typographyFonts=".json_encode($this->fontsDropdown).";\n";
?>
</script>
```

to Twig?

I did this:

```
{{ ((sectionsPreview'~groups|json_encode|raw) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In twig you can set js variables as

```
<script>

    var sectionsPreview = JSON.parse('{{ groups|json_encode() }}');
    var typographyFonts= JSON.parse('{{ fontsDropdown|json_encode() }}');

</script>
```

you may need `JSON.parse` to parse your string as json object

[json_encode](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html)

Comment: thank you
it give me somthing like this  &quot;navigations&quot;:{&quot;sections&quot;:

how can i solve this probleme

Comment: @programmerjava Do you have html elements in your json string or in groups data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this if you want that your output text

```
{{ 'sectionsPreview='~groups|json_encode() }}
```